# Setting product published date via Shopify API doesn't work properly

Tags: shopify

When I set the published_at to a furture date by using the following JSON via [Shopify product update API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#update) (https://ashop.myshopify.com/admin/products/product_id.json PUT).

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 632910392,
    "published": false,
    "published_at": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+11:00"
  }
}
```

It returned 200 and the following JSON

```
{
    "product": {
        "body_html": "something",
        "created_at": "2014-01-07T14:49:00+11:00",
        "handle": "test-product",
        "id": 206281997,
        "product_type": "MERCHANDISE",
        "published_at": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+11:00",
        "published_scope": "",
       },
    /* some other JavaScript properties*/
}
```

Shopify accepted the published date but the product was still visible. Below is the screenshot of the product Visibility
[image]

But if I removed "published_at": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+11:00" from the request JSON, the product changed to hidden.

How can I set the published date via Shopify API? Is it possible a Shopify API's bug?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution by using private API. And I tested it. Use **publish_on** instead of **published_at**. please refer to Shopify forums http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/setting-product-published-date-via-shopify-api-doesn-t-work-properly-173469